# Android MediaPlayer does not loop when its data source is from url

Tags: android, loops, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am using MediaPlayer in my app. I am following the following tutorial

http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/surface-view-playing-video

Here's part of the code

```
Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

try {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(FILE_URL));
    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Everything works fine except the video does not loop. When I set the data source a file from assets it loops just fine. But when I stream the video from URL it does not loop.

Thanks